# How to Encrypt/Decrypt using AES in WinRT?

Tags: c#, encryption, windows-8, windows-phone-8, cryptography

I am newbie in Cryptography.

Edited: It seems that I was wrong with using the right Encrypt/Decrypt algorithm so I change my question to:

How to convert these lines of codes to WinRT ?

The code is based on the code at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx

I need to do the same in WinRT:

**Update:**

**There is a Cryptography and Certificate sample for WinRT (Windows 8.1) that solved my problem.**

**Please check: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Cryptography-and-3305467b**

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        byte[] encrypted;
        using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        return encrypted;
    }
```

And

```
public static string Decrypt(byte[] cipherText)
    {
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

        string plaintext = null;

        using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {

                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream // and place them in a string.
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return plaintext;

    }
```

Comment: First of all, your Decrypt routine looks suspiciously like an Encrypt routine. Second of all, please also post the key derivation. Note that ECB is not safe, nor is your key derivation method (why do you need one in the first place?)

Comment: @owlstead Thanks for the reply. oh, The Decrypt was pasted wrongly. It is now edited and Decrypt method is now the right code. I have some resources that are used both for a Win8 app and WP8 app. I want to protect them by encryption.

Comment: Obviously using the same bytes for the first and last part of a key will halve the key size. Normally the addition of just a few rounds to the AES algorithm is not worth the cost.

Comment: @owlstead the code was base on this:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/52080335-0016-4370-889b-3afe0c0dcb7a/how-to-do-simple-aes-encryptiondecryption-in-metro

Comment: Don't just trust any crypto code on the net, that code is terrible. Best is to learn how to apply cryptography. Second best is to use a well vetted for higher level library.

Comment: @owlstead Thanks for the help. Sorry for these mess up. It is my first try using Stackoverflow. I have changed the question in a better way.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the accept and welcome to Stackoverflow. No need to be perfect here, just reasonable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but you should use the same:

- character encoding of the plaintext, such as [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf8)
- [mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation)
- [padding algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29)
- (optional) string encoding of the ciphertext, such as [base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) or the easier to debug [hexadecimal encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)

And of course the correct cipher (AES instead of Rijndael),symmetric key size and value and [IV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector). Make sure you check each of the IO to these functions *separately*. Do not rely on defaults, set each value explicitly.

Note that using ECB mode is insecure. Currently you are probably mixing CBC and ECB mode, which won't work. For secure communications you should use [authenticated encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) or a [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Authentication_Code) (using a second key).